# Geometric interpretation of duality for representations of reductive groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

For a reductive group $G$ over a nonarchimedean local field, let $\Omega$ be a connected component of the variety of cuspidal data. Let $\Omega$ have dimension $d$. Let $\mathcal{M}^f(\Omega)$ be the category of smooth $G$-modules of finite length whose Jordan Holder factors all have cuspidal datum in $\Omega$.

There is a duality $\mathcal{M}^f(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}^f(\Omega)$ that sends $\pi$ to $\text{Ext}^d(\pi,\mathcal{H}(G))$. Here $\mathcal{H}(G)$ is the Hecke algebra of $G$.

Is there an interpretation of this duality in terms of some geometric duality (something like Serre or Poincaré duality)?

Note: as a reference for everything in my post, see Bernstein's notes on $p$-adic representation theory, especially section IV.5.

Comment: My impression is that this duality is supposed to be substantially more subtle than anything coming from Serre or Poincare duality (but I am very far from an expert.) A related paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07329v3 - it does not answer your question but it may be enlightening nonetheless, explaining how the properties of this duality can be derived via the wonderful compactification.